# Rank students based on their average in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, rank

I have been researching and trying various queries to get this to work. 
What I want to happen is to rank each student based on their average which will be calculated by using AVG(grade) and this will be grouped by student_id. The table with the necessary info is as follows:

```
assessment_id | student_id | grade | subject_id
```

What I would like to see after the query is:

```
student_id | AVG(grade) | rank
```

I would also like to get the rank of a student using PHP, for example (mysql_query) WHERE student_id = '1001'

The closest I have come to getting this was by using the query below:

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(grade), (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rank 
FROM grades CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) CONST 
GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC
```

The problem with the query above is that it ranks the students based on their student_id number.

I have searched for solutions all over but they just seem to not solve what I am after. I would really appreciate your help towards this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT student_id, avg, (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rank 
FROM
 (SELECT student_id, AVG(grade) as avg
  FROM grades
  GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC) agg
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) CONST
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

Comment: Hope Im not asking too much but is there a way to assign the same rank to averages that matches and then the following student will be ranked at the row number? For example A and B scored 95 so both rank at 4 and then C with a score of 93 will rank at 6.

Comment: You should probably post it as a new question then. I don't see an easy way of doing that; it might involve calculating the maximum grade of all students in a separate subquery, then computing ranking buckets... Please consider including the table DDL and insert statements with sample data -- this will help those who might try answering.

Comment: @mustaccio it can probably be solved with modifying the `(@rn := @rn + 1)` to use a CASE expression or the IF function (and possibly with the help of an additional variable).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(grade), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC) AS rrank
FROM grades
GROUP BY student_id
```

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Please give also some explanation, how your query works.